# Query caching not working in Yii framework

Tags: php, caching, yii

I've a table containing more than 27,000 records. I want to fetch all data in Dropdown list. For that I've implemented cache but it seems to be not working as its getting very slow and showing blank page (Sometime browser is getting hanged).

Following is my code (I am using yiiboilerplate):

Configuration of backend/config/main.php in component array:

```
   'cache' => array(
        //'class' => 'system.caching.CMemCache',
        'class' => 'system.caching.CDbCache',
        'connectionID' => 'db',
    ),
```

In View page:

```
    $dependency = new CDbCacheDependency('SELECT MAX(bank_id) FROM bank');
    $bank = CHtml::listData(Bank::model()->cache(1000, $dependency)->findAll('is_active=1', array('order' => 'name')), 'bank_id', 'concatened');
    echo $form->dropDownListRow($model, 'bank_id', $bank, array(
        'empty' => 'Select'
    ));
```

I think 27000 records is not big data but still its getting very slow and I want to implement cache in my entire application.

Is my configuration correct? Where I am going wrong?

Thanks

Comment: It's quite some data for a browser (think mobile). Even if you end up populating in a acceptible time, who do you think will scroll and select some record in that long list? I think `<select>` is totally off here. You need autocomplete.

Comment: Querying 27,000 records in one go very taxing. Think of it that you're  initializing an array and populating it with 27,000 entries. Sometimes it will cause a server timeout. Doing a paging mechanism your dropdown entries will lessen your load.

Comment: @Pentium10 is right. [This html page](http://codepad.org/qrSBcYUy) consisting of only a select with 27000 identical options `Pick Me` is 64KB.  I once had a similar select with 10,000 records that kept crashing my browser.

Comment: Its not about dropdown entries. Its about findall not working with cache. Because if I am trying `Bank::model()->findall()` normally then also its getting very slow and showing blank page. And instead of findall I tried createCommand and its bit slow but showing all the records in dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

I think your parameters in `findAll` is incorrect.

It should be:

```
Bank::model()
    ->cache(1000, $dependency)
    ->findAll([
       'select' => 'bank_id',
       'order' => 'name ASC', // if it is in ascending order
       'condition' => 'is_active = 1'
    ]);
```

I don't know what `concatened` so I just ignored it. But you can always use scopes for your conditions.